# Get value closest to zero from array in MatLAB?

Tags: sorting, matlab, logic

An interesting (and probably simple) problem for you all, I have two arrays, and I need to determine the real minimum (i.e value closest to zero) and the real maximum (i.e. value furthest from zero) regardless of whether that value is positive or negative.

To do this, I have calculated the positive_max and the positive_min, as well as the negative_max and the negative_min as shown below...

```
test = [3, 4, -2, -7, 6];

positive_min = min(test(test>=0)); %Should be 3
positive_max = max(test(test>=0)); %Should be 6

negative_max = min(test(test<=0)); %Should be -7
negative_min = max(test(test<=0)); %Should be -2
```

Trouble is, I now need to compare the positive_min to the negative_min to see which is closest to zero, as well as comparing the positive_max to the negative_max to see which is furthest from zero. I can't seem to figure out how to do this...

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try using the [`abs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/abs.html) function

```
min(abs(test))
```

gives `2` and

```
max(abs(test))
```

gives `7`. If you want to find the actual signed value of each of these, you can use the second output option from [min](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) and [max](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html):

```
[~, inx] = min(abs(test));
test(inx)

ans =

    -2


[~, inx] = max(abs(test));
test(inx)

ans =

    -7
```

Comment: Thanks, using your solution combined with these if statements gave me my desired result... `if ((abs(negative_max))>= positive_max)
    max = negative_max; %Should be -7
else
    max = positive_max;
end

if ((abs(negative_min))<= positive_min)
    min = negative_min; % Should be -2
else
    min = positive_min;
end`

Comment: What I haven shown computes the value closest to zero (-2) and the value furthest from zero (-7), which is what I understood your question to be: `I need to determine the real minimum (i.e value closest to zero) and the real maximum (i.e. value furthest from zero) regardless of whether that value is positive or negative.`

Comment: Incidentally, it is a bad idea to create variables called `min` and `max` as in your comment, as these will conflict with the built-in MATLAB functions.

Comment: Aha, yes sorry, for some reason, i only saw the first part of your post. Incidentally my method (with if statements) will not work from the actual data source I need to use (a .wav file) as it returns an error of: **Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.** The data I am trying to run this process on is formatted "3.3569e-04" or "-5.5764e-09" for example, will try your method...

Comment: As I thought, your method worked brilliantly on the data! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Thanks; you enabled me to write what I wanted: a function that matches each element in a matrix to its the closest value 
[closest.m](https://gist.github.com/kwikwag/5745627)

Answer (score 0):

Matlab already takes the absolute value for max() or min() for complex numbers.
So another quick way to do this would be `min(test+1i)-1i` or `max(test+1i)-1i`